# Text file line count - different number in python2 vs python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files, python-2.x, line-count

I am reading a text file using this command:

```
print(len(list(open(filename))))
```

Now, when I run it in Python2 I get 5622862 lines, but when I read it with Python3 I get 5622865 lines. How can it be? Btw, when I do in command line `cat file.txt | wc -l` I get same result as Python2.

This is driving me nuts. Two files that should have same line length (5622862) indeed have the same length in python2, but not in python3 (5622862 vs 5622865). Can it be that python3 has a bug?

Doing a different read in python3 does not work either:

```
list(open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8"))
```

Comment: Can you remove lines from this file until the result is the same? To detect the problematic line(s). Maybe a certain line contains a char that is considered differently in Python 2 and Python3. A char that Python3 considers being a return carriage and not Python2

Comment: What numbers did you get when you tried the various values of the `newline` parameter?

Comment: @vvvvv yes, that's what I will be doing if I don't find a quicker solution. It's a bit weird that Python 3/2 is not backward compatible in this simple aspect.

Comment: @NathanB This isn't really surprising at all. Changes in how text is handled, especially unicode characters, is one of the big changes that happend for the transition of python 2 to 3.

Comment: Yes, but keeping the same function name, which behaves differently, is bad programming practice, as it makes the porting risky.

Answer (score 0):

Doing

```
print(len(list(open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8", newline="\n"))))
```

is backward compatible to Python 2